# Invalid URI error after migrating Magento and no underscore in URL

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, migration, server

I've migrated my Magento CE 1.7.0.2. to a new domain and have updated the local.xml and core_config_data table, web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url now contain the right urls. **(Installation 1)**

However upon opening the main page of my store I do get the following error:

There has been an error processing your request

Invalid URI supplied

```
a:5:{i:0;s:20:"Invalid URI supplied";i:1;s:871:"#0 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Uri.php(143): Zend_Uri_Http->__construct('http', '//my-domain...')
#1 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(726): Zend_Uri::factory('http://my-doma...')
#2 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#3 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/my-domain.com/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

The url of my Magento installation contains dashes but no underscores.

I've successfully installed a clean Magento installation (**Installation 2**) on the same server using a second database. This installation runs without problems, settings of the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url in the core_config_data table are equal.

I've also configured the clean installation (Installation 2) in such a way that it links to the database of the original Magento installation (Installation 1) surprisingly this works fine too.

I feel something is wrong with one of the Magento files of Installation 1. Anybody a clue what might cause installation 1 not to work properly?

Answer (score 6):

Check any whitespace or new line character on core_config_data table entries for base_url fields (`web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url, web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url`). I encountered this once and that's how I've resolved it.

Also another error that you may get because of this mistake is

```
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected  in lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 363
```

I would like to add this as comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my URL didn't have an underscore "_" in it.
So the solution was to erase the var/cache folder contents and also the var/session folder content.  Then refresh your page and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Spent quite some time [resolving this issue](https://www.puremedia.com.au/platforms/magento-development/) today. The Magento 2 site we were working on would not load the admin area and was exhausting all available memory. The URL was edited in the DB and had a line break after the domain name.

Check the URLS in web/unsecure/base_url & web/secure/base_url

Make sure they are clean with no spaces etc.